# Tableview items not clickable with sliding menu in combination with tab and navigation bar in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, menu, slide

I have an app with a UINavigationController an UITabBarController. I set this up in AppDelegate.m as follows:

```
...
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
BTHomeViewController *hvc = [[BTHomeViewController alloc]
                             initWithNibName:@"BTHomeViewController" bundle:nil];
//hvc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;
hvc.tabBarController.title = @"Home";
hvc.title = @"Home";  
hvc.delegate = self.menuDelegate;
UINavigationController* hvcnb = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hvc];
...

self.tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:hvcnb, svcnb, htvcnb, nil];
self.tabBarController.view.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
[self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
...
```

In this example, I do the following in the viewDidLoad of BTHomeViewController:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-button"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btnMovePanelRight:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton;
```

Now, this gives me a nice navbar and a tabbar all working as expected. I configured a delegate for all the tabbar views. If I click on the menu button the following function is activated:

```
-(void)btnMovePanelRight:(id)sender {
[delegate showMenu:self];
}
```

In this delegate (where /view/ points to BTHomeViewController), showMenu is defined as:

```
-(void)showMenu:(UIViewController*) view {
    self.menuViewController = [[BTMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BTMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIWindow* window = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];

    [window.rootViewController.view addSubview:self.menuViewController.view];
    [window.rootViewController addChildViewController:_menuViewController];
    [_menuViewController didMoveToParentViewController:window.rootViewController];

    [window.rootViewController.view sendSubviewToBack:childView];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:SLIDE_TIMING delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                            view.view.frame = CGRectMake(view.view.frame.size.width-PANEL_WIDTH, 0, view.view.frame.size.width, view.view.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             //_centerViewController.leftButton.tag = 0;
                         }
                     }];
}
```

I end up with the following (see Figure):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQsO5.png

Which is exactly what I need. However, the problem is, I cannot click any of the items in the table view. Suggestions are welcome. Thank you,

Comment: In addition to not being able to select the table items, does the table scroll?

Comment: No, I am not able to scroll in the table. It seems that the other view, **view.view**, has focus instead of the menuViewController.

Comment: I have actually tested this. Above the two labels in the screenshot, I have added a **Button**. This **Button** is still clickable when I moved the view to the right.

Comment: I would check the physical width of the view controller just to make sure you don't have its frame covering the first view when you move it over. E.g. If you have a left constraint somewhere in your xib.